# Error when using Material UI in react native

Tags: react-native

I add Material UI in my project with command:
`yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled` 
https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/

My code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function TestComponent() {
  return (
    <View>
          <Button variant="contained">Contained</Button>
        <Text>Test</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

error:
Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `style` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start component names with a capital letter.

Please help me. Thanks

I have rebuilt the project but it doesn't work, search on google with no solution

Answer (score 0):

`@emotion/react` is not React Native component, it is for the web.

If you need material UI for React Native good choice is https://reactnativepaper.com/

Answer (score 0):

As early answer said, MUI Materials are designed for the web so, many things like CSS, html tags, etc. doesn't work on mobile devices as long as an app isn't a web browser.

Fortunately, there are many alternatives to MUI, maybe the most similar to it is React Native Materials https://www.react-native-material.com/ or React Native Elements https://reactnativeelements.com/